# Implementing an interface with a return type that implements the required return type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Why can't I do this?

```
IHasOperatingSystem {
IOperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; }
} 

Computer<T> : IHasOperatingSystem where T : IOperatingSystem {
public T OperatingSystem { get; }
}
```

It's telling me that the type should be IOperatingSystem, but if T implements IOperatingSystem, shouldn't that be sufficient?

Also, I realize that the title to this question might be a little confusing, but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It's telling me that the type should be IOperatingSystem, but if T implements IOperatingSystem, shouldn't that be sufficient?

No. That's just not the way C# works. In order to implement an interface, or override a method, the parameter types and the return type have to match *exactly*. From section 13.4.4 of the C# 5 specification:

> For purposes of interface mapping, a class member A matches an interface member B when:
>
> - A and B are methods, and the name, type, and formal parameter lists of A and B are identical.
> - ...

(Here "type" should be read as "return type".)

Now you could make your `IHasOperatingSystem` type generic, of course:

```
public interface IHasOperatingSystem<T> where T : IOperatingSystem
{
    T OperatingSystem { get; }
}

public class Computer<T> : IHasOperatingSystem<T> where T : IOperatingSystem
{
    public T OperatingSystem { get { ... } }
}
```

Or alternatively you could use explicit interface implementation in the `Computer<T>` class:

```
public interface IHasOperatingSystem
{
    IOperatingSystem OperatingSystem { get; }
} 

public class Computer<T> : IHasOperatingSystem where T : IOperatingSystem
{
    // Explicit interface implementation...
    IHasOperatingSystem.OperatingSystem IOperatingSystem
    {
        // Delegate to the public property
        get { return OperatingSystem; }
    }

    public T OperatingSystem { get { ... } };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the second method. The IHasOperatingSystem interface is pretty widely used, so making it generic would be a bit more invasive than I would like. I'm still a little fuzzy on this though. Would allowing this cause issues (i.e., it would never be allowed), or is it just not allowed given how things are currently designed?

Answer (score 2):

> if T implements IOperatingSystem, shouldn't that be sufficient?

Even though it may be sufficient in other languages (Scala, I think), In C#, it is not. Return types are invariant (except for delegate return types, [which are covariant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms173174.aspx)).

A common workaround for these situations is to use generics, as such:

```
IHasOperatingSystem<T> where T: IOperatingSystem 
{
    T OperatingSystem { get; }
} 

Computer<T> : IHasOperatingSystem <T> where T : IOperatingSystem
{
    public T OperatingSystem { get; }
}
```